# I have to refresh browser all the time to view a webpage, and sometimes only text appears instead

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, internet, browser

I have to refresh my browser all the time.

Browser doesn't matter, this happens in all browsers.

The problem is when I enter a URL, sometimes the page loads fine, but most times the page won't load (keeps loading without anything happening), or it loads but only text is visible and not the pictures, OR the browser displays some strange text like "host: blabla, connection: keep-alive etc etc" (text which isn't on the webpage at all).

I have no clue what it could be... It has been bugging me for months now.

I have a network cable with a DSL connection, and I have all drivers setup from the manufacturers website for all computer components.

I run Windows XP.

I am suspecting my network card (ethernet card). It is Broadcom NetXtreme GBabit Ethernet.

Is anybody having the same issue?

If you need more input let me know...

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the network card?

Comment: it definitely has something to do with your network connection, either locally (network card), or at your router, dsl modem, cables, or your internet connection itself.  Do you have any other computers hooked up to the network?  If so, does the same thing happen on those machines or is it isolated to this one computer?

Comment: I had same issue and I fixed it by chaning my DNS address to Google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Answer (score 8):

Found this, fixed it!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txPIOi34GFU

TYPE THIS IN THE COMMAND PROMPT (make sure command prompt is run as admin)

```
1st) ipconfig /flushdns
```

Restart PC - if the problem still exists then type this:

```
2nd) netsh winsock reset
```

REBOOT, Done!

Some of you said that 'Windows 8.1 sucks because it can't access the internet'(chrome,safari etc) ..In this video i will show to fix the ERROR! ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED.  If the method in the video fix the error , please leave a like and comment.

Comment: the 2nd line here helped me, after flushing dns multiple times did not

Answer (score 4):

Sort of a stab in the dark, but often if you can see the website text but it looks formatted all strangely without images, it's a network quirk where your browser hasn't received the stylesheet for that site, and so it doesn't implement the formatting.

If this happens all the time, and you're reasonably sure it's not your network card, I would suggest you update the firmware on your router to start.

Comment: This often happens with a flaky connection. If the connection dies after your browser retrieves the page but before it retrieves the stylesheet, you get a plantext page.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue for months on my workstation and assumed it was some type of virus since my 8-year-old uses this computer all the time.

It turned out to be the network cable I was using. I switched to a new cable and the problem totally went away. I'm not saying it will be the cable in all cases, but if you have more than one computer connected to the same Internet connection via an in-home router as I do I would look for hardware problems first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems with other types of traffic? (Email, ping, FTP, chat, etc?) If not, it's **not** your hardware.

Are the other computers on the LAN having the same problems? If not, it's **not** the router.

I'd suggest some or all of the following steps:

- Make sure you're running all available patches and service packs for XP.
- Test surfing again with your software firewall disabled.
- Test surfing again with your AV software disabled. (Norton, for example, is notorious for making connections unusable.)
- Do a full virus and rootkit and nasty stuff scan.
- Update your router's firmware.
- Test your connection's throughput.
- Reset and reconfigure your router.

Comment: I use chat and ping in my website. So will it be an issue because of those?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like links to external sources for elements on the page (advertisements, style sheets etc.) are not loading, causing the page to hang or look weird.

This can often be caused by a slow/faulty DNS server.

Change your network configuration (of you PC and/or router) to use a different DNS server.  Perhaps use one of the common public ones.

While I've personally seen this problem several times, Little Helper also mentions this in his comment on the question that doing this fixed similar for him.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I found my own issue with problematic pages needing a reload each time...started with the cables on our really old router.

Three (3) cables/wire connections were loose.

I made sure they had good connection by pushing and twisting the cable and other connections.

No more problem.

Answer (score -2):

I've been struggling with this problem for over 1-1/2 years. After ruling everything else out, I had Spectrum swap out my Ubee DVW32CB integrated cable modem/router to their latest non-integrated hardware. This fixed the problem. SpeedTest results are identical.