# Browser says, it can't find the web page

Tags: internet, wireless-router, modem, redirection

If I google something and open all 10 results in new tab, 1 or 2 tabs didn't get loaded and the browser says it can't find the webpage but when i refresh, it loads perfectly.

**I feel that whenever the redirects happen from one site to another, this issue happens. For example, googling(search & open the Google results) and payment site redirects(from bank website to vendor website).**

My main concern is, I've lost money when the bank website can't redirect to the vendor website as they say the payment is pending but actually debited from my account.

Please help me to fix and if possible to understand the issue. If this is not the right place to ask this question, let me know where to post.

Additional info:

- Using Win 7 64 bit professional edition
- Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m
- ISP - Airtel
- Using laptop and connected to modem via wireless

**Edit:**

Below is the log i'm seeing in my modem,

rn_p=804a93c0
7/14/2014 8:55:35> Last errorlog repeat 139 Times
7/14/2014 8:55:35> System Error: 64 PC: 80036344
7/14/2014 8:55:35> netMakeChannDial: err=-3000 rn_p=804a93c0

7/14/2014 8:55:35> Last errorlog repeat 56 Times
7/14/2014 8:55:35> System Error: 64 PC: 80036344
7/14/2014 8:55:35> netMakeChannDial: err=-3000 rn_p=804a93c0

7/14/2014 8:55:36> Last errorlog repeat 30 Times
7/14/2014 8:55:36> System Error: 64 PC: 80036344
7/14/2014 8:55:39> netMakeChannDial: err=-3000 rn_p=804a93c0

7/14/2014 8:55:44> Last errorlog repeat 14 Times
7/14/2014 8:55:44> System Error: 64 PC: 80036344

Comment: Are you sure this happens only with websites with redirects? It could be an issue related to HTTPS websites maybe? Can you try with other secure websites like facebook for example?

Comment: Even for non secure websites, it happens. I can access the secured sites 95% of the time without any issues but randomly getting this issue for random sites.

Comment: Can you test on other devices and see if this issues takes place too? From the info I have right now, it could be anything from the ISP having issues to your router malfunctioning...

Comment: i don't have other devices to check now. when i get a chance to test on other device, will get back here with the result. thanks.

Comment: Also, you can try with another browser, and deleting cookies/cache from your current browser.

Comment: Cleared the cache and tried in IE 10, same thing happens there well. Googled for 'alien' and opened all 10 results but browser can't find this web page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien.

Comment: On going through [this](http://superuser.com/questions/194119/i-have-to-refresh-browser-all-the-time-to-view-a-webpage-and-sometimes-only-tex), i feel like, i may have problem with my wireless modem, will check.

Comment: i am facing the same problem.. what was the resolution? 
i too have airtel